# Not receiving VoIP notifications after receiving for X times

Tags: ios, swift, voip, ios13

How do I know that my device is blocked from receiving VoIP notifications?

My device stops receiving VoIP notifications after receiving for 3-4 times. 
I understand that from iOS 13 VoIP notifications should be reported to `CallKit`. Even after reporting to `CallKit` I'm going through this issue of not receiving VoIP notifications.

we have set apns-expiration to 0 and the priority to immediately(10)

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(PKPushType)type withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completion {
   if(type == PKPushTypeVoIP) {
    self.notificationMessage = payload.dictionaryPayload;

    CXProviderConfiguration* config = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"Test app"];
    config.supportsVideo = YES;
    self.provider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:config];
    [self.provider setDelegate:self queue:nil];

    CXCallUpdate* update = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    update.localizedCallerName = @"Test caller";
    update.hasVideo = YES;
    NSString *uuidString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    self.callUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];

    [self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:self.callUUID update:update completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error != nil) { NSLog(@"error: %@", error); }
        NSLog(@"----------Incoming call reported successfully--------");
        completion();
    }];
}
```

}

Handled the User action using CXProvider delegate methods

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action {
    [action fulfill];
}
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performEndCallAction:(CXEndCallAction *)action {
    if (self.callUUID == nil) {
        [action fail];
        return;
    }
   [action fulfill];
}
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you got any solution???

Comment: Instead of fulfill in both the cases, I used - self.callProvider.reportCall(with: callUUID, endedAt: Date(), reason: .remoteEnded) in performEndCallAction

Comment: And it works??? Can you please look into my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63673548/later-ios13-0-voip-notification-is-being-missing-or-delay

Comment: Please help me if you can.

Comment: I will look into it over the weekend..